AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'bfs_layout'
I just installed networkx(currently version 3.3) and I went to try their official sample code for drawing a graph with bfs layout. The code is as follow:
G = nx.path_graph(4)
pos = nx.bfs_layout(G, 0)

But I get this error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[43], line 2
      1 G = nx.path_graph(8)
----> 2 pos = nx.bfs_layout(G, 0) 

AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'bfs_layout'

Any help to fix this would be appreciated.

I tried reinstalling it via pip multiple times and it didn't work, I moved to Conda and it is working there! It might be a pip issue. (The rest of the package is working on pip,bfs_layout is the only function I faced a problem)

I can't reproduce this with the current version 3.3 (but with 3.2.1) of networkx. Try to check the version with e.g. print(nx.__version__).

You are right. It is 3.2.1. So the problem must be a pip issue. I'll other workarounds to see how can I fix this.

I finally fixed that with pip install --force-reinstall networkx.
